I need help understanding how this || works in bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
(( $1 % 3 )) || result+=Pling
(( $1 % 5 )) || result+=Plang
(( $1 % 7 )) || result+=Plong
echo ${result:-$1}

According to ChatGPT the output is supposed to be reversed, meaning when the input is 3 the output will be plangplong because the || only executes the right hand side when the left hand side is false.
I was expecting the output to be plangplong. How does this code work?

Let this be a lesson to you: ChatGPT is best suited to organizing what you already know, not for learning things you don't know.  It is known sometimes deliver falsehoods and even to hallucinate, but by design produces output that usually sounds plausible if you don't know any better.  Never ask ChatGPT or other generative AI for anything that you are not prepared to evaluate for yourself.

Instead of ChatGPT, consult Bash's manual page (man bash or https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) or its reference manual.

BTW, this isn't in any way specific to bash -- a short-circuiting logical or is a very common syntax construct, and can pretty much be used the same way across all languages with the feature.

...that said, the || isn't your point of confusion; the (( $1 % 3 )) is what's confusing you. An arithmetic expression is truthy when its output is greater than zero. What you expect is behavior identical to (( ($1 % 3) == 0 )) || result+=Pling, but that's the opposite of what your code actually does -- the actual behavior is equivalent to (( ($1 % 3) > 0 )) || result+=Pling.

Perhaps the point of confusion is that the logic involved is about the exit statuses of the (( )) commands, which are different from (though based on) the results of the arithmetic evaluations they perform.

...on which point, I've added a second linked duplicate covering that explicitly.

(As an exercise for someone who doesn't read the linked duplicates -- try running (( 0 )); echo $? -- is the result what you expect?)

@CharlesDuffy not "greater than zero" but "not zero". Negative values are are truthy too.
